# Stop apache2 from serving files and redirect to specific PHP file to handle the request

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have built a similar framework to Laravel or Express for Node.js and it is working nicely, that is until I make a request to the path that exists on the server.

Let's say I have this file structure:

```
web/
  |-- index.php # file that should handle ALL requests that come to this project
  |-- .htaccess
  |-- .env # private file that should not be accessible
  |-- test.txt
  .
  .
  .
```

When I try to request: `myweb.com/.env` it serves the file or when I define a route in the framework to `/test/a` it will try to access it and through error: 404 not found.

How can I set up my .htaccess in a way that **ALL** requests that end up `web/` will be redirected to `web/index.php` no matter if the request points to a valid file path or not.

This is how my `.htaccess` is set uped at the moment:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Indexes
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Try to remove all `RewriteCond`itions from your current .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
> ```

You don't appear to have understood the rule you are currently using. The two negated *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) prevent requests that map to phyiscal files (`-f`) and directories (`-d`) from being routed to `/index.php`. So, they are naturally left for Apache to serve them as default.

So, as a first step, you need to remove those two conditions.

(This is assuming you don't have a front-end proxy that serves your static assets - a common setup theses days. If this is the case then removing the two conditions will have no effect and you will need to configure/remove the proxy as well.)

However, the remaining rule would then cause a rewrite loop as it will unconditionally rewrite to itself (a URL-path) repeatedly. You can resolve this by rewriting to a file-path (remove the slash prefix) and use the `END` flag (Apache 2.4) instead of `L`.

For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1 [QSA,END]
```

I've also removed the `NC` flag, which was superfluous and the anchors on the regex, since `.*` is greedy by default.

You should also consider redirecting requests to remove `index.php` AND/OR the `path` URL parameter, should this be requested directly. (This is left as an exercise for the reader.)

#### Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found these 3 lines on a different stack overflow question the -f and -d when I started developing this framework couple of weeks ago. When I tried to remove them I was stuck on the endless loop as you pointed out. Also, I have released that the path argument is not needed.

Comment: @Siro You're welcome. Just to add, it's not usually desirable to rewrite _everything_ to your front-controller since you usually have static assets (JS, CSS, images, etc.) that should be served directly.

Comment: @Siro Whilst you've seemingly mentioned a `web` subdirectory in your question, I've assumed this refers to the document root, so `web` is not a public directory? Also... " when I define a route in the framework to `/test/a` it will try to access it and through error: 404 not found" - that would seem to be unrelated to this particular issue?